# set a default group to registered users with sfDoctrineGuard

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

i thought that this was going to be an easy move as what i'm trying to do sounds like, but i'm kind of new to symfony, but all i want is users who register in my web belongs to a group that is the one i use to identify frontend users, but the more i look less i found, thought that something like `setGroup('user')` was enough, but think i'm lost

some help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-users/browse_thread/thread/4556c90b2be868ed/dd420bfda5a4dfa1?lnk=gst&q=set%20default%20group%20to%20the%20new%20user#dd420bfda5a4dfa1) thread , maybe it will be helpful to you.